Javascript event listener get value
I am updating a website someone else made.
I have a calendar, and each date in the calendar has the same values
<a class="bkiavanae" href="#" id="selectiondate" data-dn="02 May 2024" data-ct="1-a">2<p style="font-size: 10px">£110</p></a>

All have the same class and id value.
I have placed an event listening to the onClick for any clicks on the class bkiavanae, which works fine.
But I need the onClick to capture the value of the data-dn value. So in this example  need it to return 02 May 2024
     var calenderSelection = document.getElementsByClassName("bkiavanae");
       for (var i = 0; i < calenderSelection.length ; i++) {
        calenderSelection[i].addEventListener("click",
         function (event) {
             event.preventDefault();
                   //alert("hello");
         },
         false);
 }


If they all have the same ID, that's invalid: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp#:~:text=The%20value%20of%20the%20id,element%20with%20the%20specific%20id.

Don't use var, use let (important for this to work), and search about "how to get HTML data values". You already have your calenderSelection[i] element

How to get data-value in the html div?

var dataDnValue = event.currentTarget.dataset.dn

Use event.target.getAttribute to retrieve the value of the data-dn attribute:
var calendarSelection = document.getElementsByClassName("bkiavanae");

for (var i = 0; i < calendarSelection.length; i++) {
  calendarSelection[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const dateValue = event.target.getAttribute("data-dn");
    alert(dateValue);
  }, false);
}


You do not handle the case where the user clicks on the  element inside the  element. Your code will alert a null value in that case. See my answer for checking the target element and accessing the parentElement when needed.

You can get that value via this.getAttribute("data-dn"):


 var calenderSelection = document.getElementsByClassName("bkiavanae");
   for (var i = 0; i < calenderSelection.length ; i++) {
    calenderSelection[i].addEventListener("click",
     function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert(this.getAttribute("data-dn"));
     },
     false);

}
<a class="bkiavanae" href="#" id="selectiondate" data-dn="02 May 2024" data-ct="1-a">2<p style="font-size: 10px">£110</p></a>
<a class="bkiavanae" href="#" id="selectiondate" data-dn="03 May 2024" data-ct="1-a">3<p style="font-size: 10px">£110</p></a>
<a class="bkiavanae" href="#" id="selectiondate" data-dn="04 May 2024" data-ct="1-a">4<p style="font-size: 10px">£110</p></a>



!!!WARNING!!!
Reusing the same id for multiple elements is invalid HTML, so I strongly advise you to either remove the ids of these tags, or, if you need some id for them, make sure they are unique in the page.

Your html code is using a dataset, so you can use the dataset property to access the value in your Javascript code.
Don't forget to handle the case where the user clicks on the p element (£11 in your example). With @john's answer you will get a null if you click on the p element. In this snippet you will get the date.


var calenderSelection = document.getElementsByClassName("bkiavanae");

for (var i = 0; i < calenderSelection.length ; i++) {
  calenderSelection[i].addEventListener("click",
    function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //alert("hello");

      if( event.target.tagName == "A" ) {
        console.log( `Data is: ${event.target.dataset.dn}`)
      }
      // If user clicked on the <p> element, then deal with it here.
      else if( event.target.parentElement.tagName == "A" ) {
        console.log( `Data is: ${event.target.parentElement.dataset.dn}`)
      }
    },
    false);
}
<a class="bkiavanae" href="#" id="selectiondate" data-dn="02 May 2024" data-ct="1-a">2<p style="font-size: 10px">£110</p></a>




You can use the dataset property on the element to get any of the data-* attributes by it's name.
If you need the id (id="selectiondate") they should be unique. Either delete the attribute OR turn int onto a data-* attribute like data-id="selectiondate". In the example I use it for testing if it is the right element that was clicked.


const calendar_div = document.querySelector('.calendar');

calendar_div.addEventListener('click', e => {
  switch(e.target.dataset.id){
    case 'selectiondate':
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e.target.dataset.dn, e.target.dataset.ct);
      break;
  }
});
<div class="calendar">
  <a class="bkiavanae" href="#" data-id="selectiondate"
    data-dn="02 May 2024" data-ct="1-a">2<p style="font-size: 10px">£110</p></a>
  <a class="bkiavanae" href="#" data-id="selectiondate"
    data-dn="03 May 2024" data-ct="1-a">3<p style="font-size: 10px">£110</p></a>
</div>



